# JQuery security error in Opera and Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, opera

I am developing an app for social network which works in `IFrame`. The app works just fine in Google Chrome and Microsoft Firefox browsers, but in Opera 12.15 JQuery library v1.10.1 fails to load with security error `Unhandled error: Security error: attempted to read protected variable` on line **1513**.

The screenshot is here:

[image: Screenshot]

It looks like the same bug exists in Internet Explorer 10.

How to deal with it?

**UPDATE:**

I have made dirty hack by commenting the lines **1513-1517** in the code of [jquery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js):

```
   // Support: IE>8
   // If iframe document is assigned to "document" variable and if iframe has been reloaded,
   // IE will throw "permission denied" error when accessing "document" variable, see jQuery #13936
  /*if ( parent && parent.frameElement ) {
        parent.attachEvent( "onbeforeunload", function() {
            setDocument();
        });
    }*/
```

The functionality of my app seems to work now, maybe it is necessary to create issue in JQuery repo...

Comment: does the `iframe` load the contents from the same domain?

Comment: @akonsu not, from the different

Comment: maybe this is the reason then. try to access it when the same domain is used and see if it works.

Comment: @akonsu But FF and Chrome work very well...

Comment: @akonsu but my application is on the other domain and it is loading in social network's iframe

Comment: it's not the same bug as described above in comments for IE8? Insert breakpoint in debugger to error line and check variables.

Comment: @maximkou do you have a link to description?

Comment: @zavg, http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13936

Comment: @maximkou in my case jquery is not loading at all

Comment: @zavg, Сlear all private data in the Opera browser and check again.

Comment: @maximkou I have just downloaded it and used it only to test my app :)

Comment: I can confirm the bug at jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SKfax/ (from the question [jquery multi level accordion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16881741/1048572)) - though that uses a very old jQuery version

Comment: @Bergi Maybe you write a comment on that issue with your jsfiddle link  (http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13980)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bug report was created - http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13980. 
Bug is now fixed.

Comment: [jQuery 1.10.2 and 2.0.3 contain the bug fix you mention.](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/07/03/jquery-1-10-2-and-2-0-3-released/)

Answer (score 0):

Add this before you include JQuery:

```
var isIE11 = !!(navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident/) && !navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE/));
if (isIE11) {
    if (typeof window.attachEvent == "undefined" || !window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent = window.addEventListener;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps, It worked for me.

Comment: It was a real bug in JQuery - please see the accepted answer.