# IE Throwing Access denied error

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, cross-domain, cors

I have 2 projects (that connect and communicate with each other) running on 2 tomcat instances. In my local i have 2 tomcats running. All is well on all the different browsers except for IE which say Access denied from loading of the Javascript files. 
So i have included a library called `https://github.com/tlianza/ajaxHooks/blob/master/src/ajax/xdr.js` that fixed my issue in **my local**.

But when i deployed the code on to DEV environment again 2 different tomcat instance( on Dev servers) i see the same error Access denied.

```
   Message: Access is denied
    URI: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js

   Message: Expected identifier, string or number
    URI: https://one.server.org/folder/js/global.js
```

Also all my files(like js/css) related to Project 1 are contained in the same tomcat instance only and not dependent on Project 2

I tried different browser setting option in IE but still same issue

I tried both URL to be launched from HTTPS:// still i see same error in IE.

So just wondering what would make IE Execute the same way as in other browsers

Comment: You can't include `https:` from a `http:` file. Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: your comment is unclear. I am running both my tomcat server that has SSL cerfication. Can you please explain what you mean

Comment: Basically, if your website was `http://example.com`, including a script from `https://foo.com` would fail, but `http://foo.com` would not.

Comment: Actually I am loading the foo.com inside of the example.com iframe

Comment: That doesn't really change anything. The parent page and the page in the iframe should be working independantly.

Comment: is their any library that help with IE issue i am having

Comment: First we have to figure out what the issue is.

Comment: Yes Kevin. that is correct. they both work independently

Comment: 1- Just download jquery and global.js...and 2- Use it this way <script type='text/javascript' src='localjsfolder/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>

Comment: I did that too. but did not work. the problem is as if IE is not recognizing the file

Comment: @KevinB, this work fine in IE when both projects running in one tomcat instance. but the Access denied error pop up when running on 2 different tomcats in Dev. In local(one machine and 2 tomcat instance, just port changes localhost:8080/ localhost:8081 change) after including the xdr.js  the issue resolved. But cropped in Dev as one said one.server.cool.org and the other said two.server.hot.org

Comment: Are you trying to access the iframe from teh parent page, or the parent page from the iframe?

Comment: NO i am not doing that. So the content of the parent page is loading fine. But the content inside of the iframe is what throwing the errors described in the post

Comment: Have you looked at the network waterfall in the F12 networking tab to see what the request/response actually look like? You can also use Fiddler to get http info.

Comment: also instead of using https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js us //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js so the request matches to the request type your site uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently what worked for me is changing the Jquery library to 1.10.0. Jquery 1.10.1 had bug that made IE throw access denied error.this post was useful 
"[Preventing "SCRIPT5: Access is denied" error in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17370482/preventing-script5-access-is-denied-error-in-ie?rq=1)"

tested in IE8/IE9/IE10