# how to find <DIV> by class name and remove javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have `<div>` that has class name, I want to find this by class name and remove it in `javascript` i used `$(".popUpContainer").remove()` but not work in IE9. How I can do it that work in every browsers?

```
<div class="popUpContainer">
</div>
```

Comment: Should work, even in IE9. Does the script run? What if you change the class name? What if you find by id instead of class? Think, think think ... it's called debugging.

Comment: As previously stated, it *should* work. Check the console for errors. Maybe the page was cached and the script didn't even run when you checked. As far as I know, all versions of jQuery support IE9; you could check to see if another version works as a last resort..

Comment: that works even in IE6. Show full code

Comment: You did include jQuery library in the document, right?

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20360719/ie-throwing-access-denied-error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is script error in jquery versions less than 1.10.1. Try using version 1.11.0. Its working fine in IE. Check the fiddle.

```
$(function() {
    $('div.ikur').remove();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8mfwF/3/

Answer (score 0):

try this in pure javascript:

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('.myClass');
var button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var parent = elem.parentNode; // I did that for IE support
  parent.removeChild(elem);
});
```

```html
<div class="myClass">Hello!</div>
<button>Remove</button>
```

Comment: IE doesn't support this method. You still have to use `elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem)`;