# jQuery fails to access a local HTML file | SCRIPT70: Permission denied

Tags: javascript, jquery, policy

I have to implement an existing frameset with JavaScript/jQuery. I´ve embedded the developer version jQuery JavaScript Library v1.9.0.

Every time the right-frame loaded a new HTML-file a function will check the content of this new loaded document. This process will fail sometimes, it´s not possible to understand when (and why) because it occurs randomly.

This is the line which will try to access the frames content:

```
var Jrightframe  = $(iframe.find('frameset#myID frameset frame[name="right"]').get(0).contentWindow.document);
```

Sometimes, as I said it above, the message will be:

> SCRIPT70: permission denied jquery.js, line 3882 character 2

I think it´s a same origin policy problem because I tried this locally (C: partition). But what is the problem to load a file from the partition if the js-script runs on the same partition?

Can somebody please help me to find out what´s going on here?

Comment: This post seems to have some info on it being an old jQuery bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17370482/preventing-script5-access-is-denied-error-in-ie

Comment: Actually I already posted the error I get in the console!

Comment: Apologies!! I'll edit :) (Along with a possible fix)

Comment: IMHO the option that the js is quicker than the iframe is impossible, because the function handler calls the function which will access the frames content only on load .load()

Comment: I have read the thread and tried to use it with jquery jquery-1.10.0.min.js as they recommended, but that didn´t solve the problem. it is also a different error message

Answer (score 0):

I searched a long time and found multiple problems like my problem. Ok here is what solved the problem:
Update the jquery core to v1.11.0. It seems only to appear in older versions.